# "Cannot update File menu Recent Files list [Errno 13] Permission denied: recent-files.lst" when I open IDLE (Python 3.4 GUI)

Tags: python, python-idle

I have no idea why this happens and then it doesn't come up with any typing cursor even when I click so I can't edit anything. I'm running Windows 10, and Python 3.4.4. Anyone know why this is happening?

> Cannon update File menu Recent Files list. Your operating system says:
>
> [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>
> 'C:\Users\Aaron\.idlerc\recent-files.lst'

Solved, my .idlerc folder was hidden, after making it visible everything worked fine.

Comment: Have you removed the .idlerc folder, or set it to hidden?

Comment: @Reti43 Oh it's hidden. I have now made it visible and it's working fine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

If the `recent-files.lst` file is hidden, Python will fail to access it properly. You most likely tried to hide the `.idlerc` folder and applied the same settings to any subfolders. You can still keep that folder hidden, because it's ugly, but make sure not to set the `recent-files.lst` file to hidden, too.

Answer (score 0):

Clear all content within `recent-files.lst` and as `breakpoints.lst` and then restart Python IDLE.